# Javascript: I want to achieve something like async/await in my program. But the blocks of my code aren't promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, async-await, es6-promise

In my success of my ajax, I'm getting location of my pdf file. I want to open it.
But the problem is:
It takes some time to open the pdf with window.open(), so before that I want to render it on the background and I want to display the console data.And after its totally rendered it should show me the pdf file.
I want to wait for the pdf to open like resolve of a promise.

```
window.open(response);      

  let html = `
    It goes to my console div. 
    `;            
  $(document).find('#bottom-tab-content').html(html);
```

I also have tried to put the html section on top of window.open().. but its not helping. I want to know if my pdf it has loaded.

Comment: Is `response` on the same domain? If so, you can probably use a `load` listener

Comment: @CertainPerformance - If it's a PDF being opened, not a web page, probably not. But that's the only thing I can think of to *try*.

Comment: If you can't do it with callbacks, you can't do it with promises or `async`/`await` either.

Comment: i'm getting response from php. need something like promise or a callback right? .. yes its on a same domain.. wait let me try

Comment: @Bergi any other way.. hmm .. My system looks bad

Comment: @CertainPerformance  I'm trying it on my success:function(response){).. can you hep me how I can use the window.load to check my my response is loaded? .. response is something like "/uploads/sth.pdf".

Comment: @ReyYoung I just meant to say that you need to get it working first, without promises (e.g. by finding the appropriate event to listen for or doing polling or whatever - I don't know the solution), then we can look into making it pretty with `async`/`await`.

Comment: Please change the title of your post to describe the problem being solved such as "How to know when a PDF being opened in a new window is done rendering?"

Comment: @jfriend00 its not only about that sir.. I just want to know if its possible using promises in just a block of code

Answer (score -3):

You can try to implement this using jQuery.deferred. I made a sample function for that will wait async for pdfGeneration and then will open it, once it will be ready.

```
function getPDF() {
    return '';
}

getPdf()
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('response here' + response);
    window.open(response);
  }).fail(function(){
      console.error('failed reposne');
  });
```

Answer (score -3):

You could make a callback function.

so for example.

```
function displaySomething(text) {
        console.log('Hello, lets say '+text);
}

function firstFunction(callback, text) {
        console.log('So I am running first, mkeiii');

    callback(text)
}

firstFunction(displaySomething, 'mkeiii');
```

If it's to big of a code, then it can be a headacke to figirue it out how to put everything in brackets, but if its small peace of code you need to run before you get a response then it could do it. So in theory you could do this.

```js
function loadPDF(link) {
  console.log(link);
}

function loadAjax(callback) {
    console.log('print console data');
  //Do your ajax call. On succsess call back to other function.
    //ON SUCCSESS display link
       callback('http')
}

loadAjax(loadPDF);
```

Clearly the OP doesnt want any suggestions or discussions, he wants a peace of code that would work without any questions.